# JQuery - Animate Scroll but NOT on click but on Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I know I can use the "click" event and make jquery scroll to a certain div as follows:

```
('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( '#div' ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

What I would like to do is to detect a scroll and upon that and based on the height of the window, make jquery scroll to different locations.

I tried the following which works partially but it will not allow me to scroll back to the top once the animate event is triggered.

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).height() < 990) {
            goToByScroll('about');
        }else if($(this).height() < 500){
            goToByScroll('contact');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Any ideas?!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what are you doing, but your javascript conditional is wrong.
So if you put `< 990` in first conditional, all height < 990 will go to that result, it will never go to second if.
See this updated code.

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}

var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
        // downscroll code
        if (scrollTop < 500) {
            goToByScroll('contact');
        }else if(scrollTop < 990){
            goToByScroll('about');
        }
    } else {
        // upscroll code
        if (scrollTop > 990) {
            goToByScroll('about');
        }else if(scrollTop > 500){
            goToByScroll('contact');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: To give more explanation, I want that when a user start scrolling down that he/she gets to the first div that is below the intro. Then if he/she scrolls more than jquery would that them to the second div below. Etc - <div id="first"></div> --> scroll go to <div id="second-below-first"></div> - scroll go to <div id="thrid-below-second"></div> etc

Comment: Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve: http://mediaboom.com/ - You can scroll down and you will see what I mean.